# I need a new way to detect if there has been a change to an elements HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, detect

Right now im trying to find a way to detect when an elements HTML has changed.

I'm currently trying:

```
var a, b;
setInterval(function() {
    a = $('#chat').text();
}, 150);
setInterval(function() {
    b = $('#chat').text();
    if (a !== b) {
        alert("There has been a new message.");
    }
}, 200);​
```

What I do is every 150 milliseconds I check for the HTML of #chat and then every 200 seconds I check the HTML again and then check if variable `a` does not equal to variable `b` them in the future I will so something with that but for right now I just alert something.

You can see it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/MT47W/

Obviously this way is not working and is not very accurate at all.
Is there a better/different to do/achieve this?

Thanks for any help, I've been trying to figure out how to do this a better for about a week now but I just can't find a fix for this and i'm hoping I posted this problem at the right place, and at the right time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `var` to store the element's current `text` then check against it in a `setInverval` and update the `var` to store the current `text` after checking:

```
var a = $('#chat').text();
setInterval(function() {
    if (a !== $('#chat').text()) { //checks the stored text against the current
        alert("There has been a new message."); //do your stuff
    }
    a = $('#chat').text(); //updates the global var to store the current text
}, 150); //define your interval time, every 0.15 seconds in this case
```

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/MT47W/3/)

You may as well store the value in the  [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)  of the element to avoid using globals.

Example using `.data()`:

```
$('#chat').data('curr_text', $('#chat').text());
setInterval(function() {
    if ($('#chat').data('curr_text') !== $('#chat').text()) {
        alert("There has been a new message.");
    }
     $('#chat').data('curr_text', $('#chat').text());
}, 150);
```

***[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/MT47W/4/)***

Another approach, to save client's memory, you can just store the number of child `div`s your `#chat` element has:

```
$('#chat').data('n_msgs', $('#chat').children().length);
setInterval(function() {
    if ($('#chat').data('n_msgs') !== $('#chat').children().length) {
        alert("There has been a new message.");
    }
     $('#chat').data('n_msgs', $('#chat').children().length);
}, 150);
```

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/MT47W/5/)

---

**EDIT:** Here's my very final addition, with a [DOM mutation event listener](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MutationEvent):

```
$('#chat').on('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
    alert("There has been a new message.");
});
```

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/MT47W/7/) (not tested in IE < 8)

**Note:** As noted in the comments, even though mutation events are still supported they're classed as [deprecated by W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents) due to the performance loss and some incompatibilities across different browsers, therefore it's suggested to use one of the solutions above and only use DOM Mutation events when there's no other way around.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I'm pretty sure listening to DOM events is not very well supported and removed from the latest specs altogether.

Comment: @VahurRoosimaa, I might be mistaken, but jQuery works mostly on DOM event listening for event delegation and I see it being broadly used in answers lately. Now, if it brings any compatibility issue, any of the older revisions will also work. =] Or did you mean, DOM mutation events specifically?

Comment: Wow thanks so much. I never heard of: DOMNodeInserted and not sure if that would be well supported as Vahur said so I think ill use the second method. But thanks for all these ways. But I also did think of using data of just getting the length of the children in #chat. Well I learn something new everyday! :)

Comment: @Shawn31313 Same. =] If anyone has more info on the DOM mutation events being deprecated, feel free to share and I'll make an edit in the answer. All I've found so far is that the mutation events degrade performance, I'll add a note a avoid using those in the answer.

Comment: @VahurRoosimaa Yes you're right, I found some material on w3c and added a note to avoid using DOM *mutation* events unless strictly necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Just checking the last chat would improve efficiency and also do what you want. The only way that it would not work is if the same person sends the same message twice - which most likely will not happen.

I hope this would work:

```
 var lastMessage = $('#chat .body').last().text();
    function checkMessages(){
        var newLastMessage = $('#chat .body').last().text();
        if(lastMessage !== newLastMessage && $('#chat .body').last().length > 0){
             //message has changed
            alert("There has been a new message.");
            lastMessage = $('#chat .body').last().text();
        }
        setTimeout(function(){checkMessages();},1000);
    }
    checkMessages();
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2wrX/)

Comment: What if the same user posts the same message twice? Your function doesn't fire for spammers :P

Comment: Good point. However, I'm fairly sure that the user won't want to get continuous notifications from spammers. Also, it won't really matter because the "new message" is basically the same message. :D

Comment: What browsers don't support setInterval?

Comment: My apologies, I had a browser compatability problem with setInterval in the past in one of my own scripts. However, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval, it is supported in IE 4 and above. I shall remove that part....

Answer (score 1):

Use crc32 or md5 hashing to check whether data has changed. Just get the html content of the div that you want to check, hash it as a string with either crc32 or md5 and you'll get a string that will represent that content. Use a hidden timestamp etc to be sure that multiple messages by one user get a different hash. If you do this in a setInterval callback, you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Although it **is not highly recommended**, it is also possible to use [Paul Irish's Duck punching](http://paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/) method to tie into jQuery's append function - if you know for sure that the `append` function is how content is being added ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/MT47W/8/)):

```
(function($) {
    // store original reference to the method
    var _old = $.fn.append;
    $.fn.append = function(arg) {
        // append as usual
        _old.apply(this, arguments);

        // do your own checking here
        // "this" is a jQuery object
        if (this[0].id === "chat") {
            alert('there is a new message!');
        }
        return this;
    };

})(jQuery);
```

With this method, no timing loops are needed.